# Número aleatório entre 0 e 8, exceto 5, no JavaScript usando Math.random

Tags: javascript, random

Olá, usando JavaScript, preciso gerar um número aleatório entre o **0** e **8**, porém o número **5** não pode ser um desses números gerados.

Eu estou retornando esse números até o momento usando a seguinte função:

```
return(Math.floor(Math.random()*9));
```

Porém, o código acima apenas gera qualquer número de **0** a **8**.

Como faço para retornar um número aleatório que não seja o **5**?

Caso exista outra maneira de fazer isso sem usar a função Math.random, também será útil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solução rápida:

```
var numero = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
return numero>4 ?  numero+1 : numero
```

### Explicação:

Tem muitas maneiras de fazer, mas vou elaborar uma bem simples para o seu caso.

Primeiro, vamos entender o problema. Você quer uma de oito possibilidades, mas a saída não é sequencial:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 <-- posição sequencial dos números (aqui é feito o random)
0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 <-- saída desejada (simplesmente modificamos o retorno com if)
```

Então você quer algum desses oito números. Ou seja:

```
var numero = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
```

São duas sequências, de zero a quatro, e de seis a oito, então basta somar um se for maior que quatro:

```
return numero>4 ?  numero+1 : numero
```

Se der 0 1 2 3 4 retorna 0 1 2 3 4 respectivamente... 
... e, se der 5 6 7 retorna 6 7 8 respectivamente

Ficando assim o código:

```
var numero = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
return numero>4 ?  numero+1 : numero
```

Caso não conheça o operador condicional (chamado de ternário) é o mesmo que fazer isso:

```
var numero = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
if (numero>4) {
   return numero + 1;
} else {
   return numero;
}
```

Teste aqui:

```js
function randomDeZeroAOitoMenosOCinco() {
   var numero = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
   return numero>4 ? numero + 1 :numero;
}

document.getElementById('sortear').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = randomDeZeroAOitoMenosOCinco();
};
```

```html
<button id="sortear">Clique-me!</button>
<span id="resultado">?</span>
```

### E se fosse uma sequência mais complexa?

Sempre que pensar em random de coisas variadas (carta de baralho, números não sequenciais, nomes) pense neles como "ítens" e numere sequencialmente (mesmo que sejam números, dá pra "numerar cada um deles em sequencia"). Aí você sorteia o índice dele, e depois pega o valor:

```
var possibilidades = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 ];
return possibilidades[Math.random()*possibilidades.length];
```

Notou que neste caso você pode por no *array* a sequência que quiser?

Teste aqui:

```js
function randomCustomizado() {
   var possibilidades = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 ];
   return possibilidades[Math.floor(Math.random()*possibilidades.length)];
}

document.getElementById('sortear').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = randomCustomizado();
};
```

```html
<button id="sortear">Clique-me!</button>
<span id="resultado">?</span>
```

Comment: Excelente. No meu caso da pergunta, essa parte do código está dentro de um switch case, pois estou criando um jogo da memória para aprender JavaScript (sou iniciante). Com apenas algumas modificações da sua solução colocando dentro de uma função recursiva, funcionou aqui.

Comment: @IgorPedra acrescentei uma função mais interessante ao final, que serve para qualquer sequência (e até mesmo para strings).;

Comment: Se lembrar disso, vai ajudar muito quando precisar de "random" de ítens variados: numere os ítens (no seu caso seria como pegar os valores que você quer e numerar de zero a oito, sendo que o quinto valor é o seis, e assim por diante) , facilita o raciocínio.

Answer (score 3):

Nessa função nunca vai dar cinco:

```
function numberRandom() {
    let num = 5
    while (num === 5) {
        num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)
    }
    return num
}
```

Comment: Dessa maneira de fato nunca dará cinco, mas note que o sorteio em si acaba não sendo determinístico (o loop pode ter que executar várias vezes em seguida até sortear um número que não seja cinco) - Para fins de um teste rápido funciona, mas se for gerar uma quantidade grande de números vai acabar tendo mais de 11% de retrabalho em média (chance de dar 5 e ter que sortear de novo)